# views not populating in gridlayout recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

I am trying to load data from an api online but am having an issue with the views loading.  When I try to run the emulator, a blank screen shows up.  Any idea why?  I am guessing my issue is somewhere within how I am loading the gridview but I have not been able to figure it out.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String SEARCH_TERM = "popular";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private List<Movie> movieData;

    /*
    API KEY
    https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=1f5029b7d824dee72f4d4a156dac90ed
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movieData);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

        movieData = new ArrayList<>();

        loadMovieData();
    }

    private void loadMovieData() {
        new FetchMovieTask().execute(SEARCH_TERM);
    }

    public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            final String MOVIES_RESULTS = "results";
            final String MOVIES_POSTER_IMAGE = "poster_path";
            final String MOVIES_TITLE = "title";
            final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
            URL moviesUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(SEARCH_TERM);
            try {
                String jsonMoviesResponse = NetworkUtils.getReponseFromHttpUrl(moviesUrl);

                JSONObject moviesJson = new JSONObject(jsonMoviesResponse);

                JSONArray moviesArray = moviesJson.getJSONArray(MOVIES_RESULTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {

                    String moviePoster;
                    String movieTitle;
                    String movieReleaseDate;
                    JSONObject movie = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    moviePoster = ("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + movie.getString(MOVIES_POSTER_IMAGE));
                    movieTitle = movie.getString(MOVIES_TITLE);
                    movieReleaseDate = movie.getString(RELEASE_DATE);

                    Log.i("MoviteTitle", movieTitle);
                    Log.i("ReleaseDate", movieReleaseDate);
                    Log.i("Image", moviePoster);

                    Movie data = new Movie(movieTitle, movieReleaseDate, moviePoster);

                    movieData.add(data);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieAdapterViewHolder>{

    private List<Movie> mMovieData;
    private Context context;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movieData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mMovieData = movieData;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTitleTextView.setText(mMovieData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.mReleaseDateTextView.setText(mMovieData.get(position).getDate());
        Picasso.with(context).load(mMovieData.get(position).getMoviePoster()).into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview_item, parent, false);
        return new MovieAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mMovieData)
            return 0;
        return mMovieData.size();
    }

    public class MovieAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView mTitleTextView;
        public final TextView mReleaseDateTextView;
        public final ImageView mImageView;

        public MovieAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTitleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
            mReleaseDateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.release_date_text_view);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Movie Class

```
public class Movie {
    private String Title;
    private String Date;
    private String MoviePoster;

    public Movie(String title, String date, String moviePoster) {
        Title = title;
        Date = date;
        MoviePoster = moviePoster;
    }

    public Movie() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public String getMoviePoster() {
        return MoviePoster;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }

    public void setMoviePoster(String moviePoster) {
        MoviePoster = moviePoster;
    }
}
```

Comment: move this `movieData = new ArrayList<>();` before creating adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info : Java is all pass by value.

Issue : you are passing empty list reference to adapter and later initialising the list but in adapter it is still null so adapter will never receive the added value in list so do

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

movieData = new ArrayList<>();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ do it before
mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movieData);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);    
loadMovieData();
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding